# Does chewing gum mentally help basketball players make foul shots?

Tags: sport-psychology

I often see basketball players chew gum while making foul shots.

Does this help in their accuracy?
Any embodied cognitive explanation for this?

Answer (score 8):

Chewing gum increases heart rate and blood pressure through muscular exercise (Farella, Bakke, Michelotti, Marotta & Martina, 1999) and enhances mental performance through improved delivery of glucose to the brain (Stephens & Tunney, 2004).

I could not find any references to embodiment playing a role in the effects of chewing.

---

Sources:

- Farella, M., Bakke, M., Michelotti, A., Marotta, G., & Martina, R. (1999). Cardiovascular responses in humans to experimental chewing of gums of different consistencies. *Archives of Oral Biology, 44*, 835-842.
- Stephens, R., & Tunney, R. J. (2004). Role of glucose in chewing gum-related facilitation of cognitive function. *Appetite, 43*, 211-213.